# How to print array elements in textview with a delay

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to print all the elements of an Array of Strings one by one in the same textview with 1 second delay between each element, but the only thing is printed is the last element.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tv2;
    private String []numbers={"1","2","3","4","5"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv2=findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    }

    public void initiate(View view){

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
                    tv2.setText(numbers[i]);
                    tv2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv2.setText("");
                        }
                    },1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I intent to overwrite it, I want to show only one element at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

**UPDATE**

```
public void initiate(View view){
     int i = 0;
     new CountDownTimer((number.lenght*10000),1000){

                           @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                           @Override
                           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                if(i<numbers.length)
                                   tv2.setText(numbers[i++]);
                           }

                           @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                           
                            }
                      }.start();
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for contributing, I am just a starter in the coding world, can you clarify where do you get the "i" variable?

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try it like the following?

```
class DispatchGroupManager {
    var count: Int = 0
    var runnable: Runnable? = null

    constructor() {
        count = 0
    }

    @Synchronized fun enter() {
        count ++
    }
    @Synchronized fun leave() {
        count --
        notifyGroup()
    }

    fun notify(r: Runnable) {
        runnable = r
        notifyGroup()
    }

    fun notifyGroup() {
        if(count <= 0 && runnable != null) {
            runnable!!.run()
        }
    }
}
```

```
val requestGroup = DispatchGroupManager()

for(t in this.numbers) {
    
    requestGroup.enter()

    // tv2.setText(numbers[i]);
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(object : Runnable {
         override fun run() {

             //tv2.setText("");
             requestGroup.leave()

          }
    },1000)
}

requestGroup.notify(Runnable {
        
})
```